# python schedule not running all the jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, schedule

I am using [python schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module to schedule a bunch (40+) of daily recurring jobs on an heroku (Hobby Tier) instance. I run a script as a entry point (called on every reboot of the machine):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     schedule.every().day.at(session_time).do(_run_leetcode_session, bot, chat_id, team_name=team_name)
```

Out of the ~40 jobs I schedule, looks like some of them are not run. To. verify I run the following debug script:

```
for job in schedule.jobs:
         logging.info(job)
```

And I get the following log

```
2020-03-05 23:06:31,606 - root - INFO - Every 1 day at 12:00:00 do _run_leetcode_session(<telegram.bot.Bot object at 0x7f9576039b50>, '-375976592', team_name='Leetcode Team 100') (last run: 2020-03-05 12:00:01, next run: 2020-03-06 12:00:00)
2020-03-05 23:06:31,606 - root - INFO - Every 1 day at 15:30:00 do _run_leetcode_session(<telegram.bot.Bot object at 0x7f9576039b50>, '-281586101', team_name='Leetcode Practice 201') (last run: [never], next run: 2020-03-05 15:30:00)
```

The first line is fine, but the log exhibits a non-expected behaviour in the second line:
at `2020-03-05 23:06:31` I am being told that `(last run: [never], next run: 2020-03-05 15:30:00)`, in fact the job wasn't executed on `2020-03-05 15:30:00` and now the next run date is in the past.  **How to interpret this?**

Is this a bug in the library? Is there a problem in the machine? Is there some problem with the threading set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because python `schedule` module **does not handle errors** automatically, so if one job breaks the scheduler breaks and all the following jobs will be not executed.

A workaround is using an implementation that catches exceptions like this [SafeScheduler](https://gist.github.com/mplewis/8483f1c24f2d6259aef6)